# replace addition operation with bit-shifting

Tags: c, math, bit-manipulation

In my embedded code I need to add offsets 0x100, 0x200, 0x300 etc. (overall number of offsets is fixed, say 64) to initial register address. Is it possible to optimize it with bit shifting? I know that multiplication by 2 is left bit-shifting by 2, but I can't get my head around addition operation.

Comment: no, addition is not equivalent with shifting. what makes you think that shifting would be more "optimal" (or even if it was, that you need that) than addition?

Comment: Addition is typically a single-cycle operation. No way to beat that.

Comment: It would be possible with `OR`-ing, if the initial address less than `0x100`. But on most ALUs the addition is not slower than logical operations, so why bother..

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace addition with bit shifting. Only multiplication can. This is because left-shift(`<<`) multiplies by x * 2^n. So

```
(1 << 3) == 1 * pow(3, 2)
```

Right shift(`>>`) divides x / 2^n.

Doing bit shifting instead of the equivalent multiplying/dividing is faster, and is usually used in games, where performance is critical.